# How do I get a client's IP address from inside a soap service?(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, soap, soapserver

I am written a soapService using the [soap package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap), I'm passing an express server to it.

The problem is that the server can get requests from 2 different network interfaces, and I want which one the request came from.

My solution is to get client's IP and determine which interface it came from using

```
require("os").NetworkInterfaces()
```

but I couldn't find how to get a client's IP

I tried:
this.req.ip, this.httpHeaders["x-forwarded-for"] || this.req.connection.remoteAddres but it comes as undefined

Edit: I want to add a minimal example for testing.

3 files are created:
soapserver.js (that includes the soap service where I want to get the ip from inside of it)
client.js (to call the soapservice)
check_username.wsdl (used to create the service)

soapserver.js:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var http = require('http');
const util = require('util');
const app = require("express")()

var myService = {
    CheckUserName_Service: {
        CheckUserName_Port: {
            checkUserName: function(args, soapCallback) { 
                console.log('checkUserName: Entering function..');
                console.log(args);
                /*
                 * Where I'm trying to get clietn's IP address
                 */
                soapCallback("{'username found'}");
            }
        }
    }   
};


var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('check_username.wsdl', 'utf8');
var server = require("http").Server(app);    
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);
    console.log(req.ip);
});

var port = 8000;
server.listen(port);

var soapServer = soap.listen(server, '/test', myService, xml);
soapServer.log = function(type, data) {
    console.log('Type: ' + type + ' data: ' + data);
};

console.log('SOAP service listening on port ' + port);
```

client.js:

```
"use strict";

var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/test?wsdl';

var options = { endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/test'};
var requestArgs = { userName: "TEST_USER" };
soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
      console.error("An error has occurred creating SOAP client: " , err);  
  } else {
      var description = client.describe();
      console.log("Client description:" , description);
      var method = client.checkUserName;
      method(requestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
        //response envelope
        console.log('Response Envelope: \n' + envelope);
        //'result' is the response body
        console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));
      });
  }
});
```

check_username.wsdl

```
<definitions name = "CheckUserNameService"
   targetNamespace = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/CheckUserNameService.wsdl"
   xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/CheckUserNameService.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <message name = "CheckUserNameRequest">
      <part name = "userName" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>
   <message name = "CheckUserNameResponse">
      <part name = "status" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>
   <portType name = "CheckUserName_PortType">
      <operation name = "checkUserName">
         <input message = "tns:CheckUserNameRequest"/>
         <output message = "tns:CheckUserNameResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name = "CheckUserName_Binding" type = "tns:CheckUserName_PortType">
      <soap:binding style = "rpc"
         transport = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name = "checkUserName">
         <soap:operation soapAction = "checkUserName"/>
         <input>
            <soap:body encodingStyle = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace = "urn:examples:CheckUserNameService" use = "encoded"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body encodingStyle = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace = "urn:examples:CheckUserNameService" use = "encoded"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name = "CheckUserName_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for CheckUserNameService</documentation>
      <port binding = "tns:CheckUserName_Binding" name = "CheckUserName_Port">
         <soap:address
            location = "http://www.examples.com/CheckUserName/" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: You've started your SOAP server on `/test`, but trying to get `clientIP` from `/`? Am I missing something here? `req.connection.remoteAddress` will give you the client IP on `/test`.

Comment: @JishanShaikh no I want to do something similar from inside the soap service code,  where I  left "Where I'm trying to get clietn's IP address" comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for my case and probably would be of use for someone wanting to do something similar.

I have 2 potential solutions:

1/ I modified 'node-soap' package, in `server.js` I passed the IP (from req Object) to `_process`  than have it included in argument that are going to be passed  `obj.Body[methodName]["ip"] = ip;`

2/ The goal was to find which network interface is coming from, so the second solution involves binding the server to only one interface (instead of 0.0.0.0) and have one server by interface.

I went with the former in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There you go, the code. Working on Localhost as well as remoteProd (cloud hosted).

**Edit:** Code now tested and modified for remote client IPs as well.

**server.js**

```js
var soap = require('soap');
var http = require('http');
const util = require('util');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = require("express")()
var myService;

newApp = app;
var server = http.Server(app);
var port = 8000;
server.listen(port);
console.log("http server started listtening on " + port);

newApp.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
    var clientIP = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    //console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress); // will always give server ip on remote connections
    myService = {
        CheckUserName_Service: {
            CheckUserName_Port: {
                checkUserName: function (args, soapCallback) {
                    console.log('checkUserName: Entering function..');
                    console.log(args);
                    //console.log(this.request.connection.remoteAddress)
                    /*
                     * Where I'm trying to get clietn's IP address
                     */
                    console.log("***")
                    console.log("IP of client: " + clientIP);
                    console.log("***")
                    //console.log(request.connection.remoteAddress);
                    // res = this.request.connection.remoteAddress;
                    //console.log(args)
                    soapCallback("{'username found'}");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('myservice.wsdl', 'utf8');


    var soapServer = soap.listen(server, '/test', myService, xml);
    soapServer.log = function (type, data) {
        console.log('Type: ' + type + ' data: ' + data);
    };
    console.log('SOAP service listening on port ' + port);
});

// Need first request to boot up soapservice
fetch('http://localhost:8000/', {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("fetch then + first from server");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("fetch error + first from server: " + error);
    })
```

**client.js**

```js
"use strict";

var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/test?wsdl';

var options = {
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/test'
};
var requestArgs = {
    userName: "TEST_USER"
};

// If you comment out this request, server will log server's IP (first fetch)
fetch('http://localhost:8000/', {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("fetch then from client");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("fetch error from client: " + error);
    })

soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error has occurred creating SOAP client: ", err);
    } else {
        var description = client.describe();
        console.log("Client description:", description);
        var method = client.checkUserName;
        method(requestArgs, function (err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
            console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    }
});
```

**myservice.wsdl**: Notice that I renamed it, idk why.

```xml
<definitions name = "CheckUserNameService"
   targetNamespace = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/CheckUserNameService.wsdl"
   xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/CheckUserNameService.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <message name = "CheckUserNameRequest">
      <part name = "userName" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>
   <message name = "CheckUserNameResponse">
      <part name = "status" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>
   <portType name = "CheckUserName_PortType">
      <operation name = "checkUserName">
         <input message = "tns:CheckUserNameRequest"/>
         <output message = "tns:CheckUserNameResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name = "CheckUserName_Binding" type = "tns:CheckUserName_PortType">
      <soap:binding style = "rpc"
         transport = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name = "checkUserName">
         <soap:operation soapAction = "checkUserName"/>
         <input>
            <soap:body encodingStyle = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace = "urn:examples:CheckUserNameService" use = "encoded"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body encodingStyle = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace = "urn:examples:CheckUserNameService" use = "encoded"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name = "CheckUserName_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for CheckUserNameService</documentation>
      <port binding = "tns:CheckUserName_Binding" name = "CheckUserName_Port">
         <soap:address
            location = "http://www.examples.com/CheckUserName/" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: I am yet to test it correctly (from 2 different IPs) but you have tried running the cient code from 2 different IPs and it gave you the correct client IP ?!

Comment: Yes, now I've confirmed with updated code.

Comment: no, it's not what I'm looking for, your solution fixes it through a self-request, which I don't get why you did it. But I tested it with 2 different client requests in the same local network and it didn't give the output I'm looking to get (the IP of the client)

Comment: The method `req.connection.remoteAddress` and related req methods getting data are from request headers of an HTTP request, SOAP has different request/response headers. For your problem of getting a client IP (since you are creating an HTTP server for a SOAP service), I used the same server to create a request to get IP from that header. If you don't want to use an HTTP request, generate a client IP from, e.g., `node-ip` package, and pass it into the SOAP request header to get it to the server.

Comment: I don't believe you are getting the wrong client IPs, tell me your exact code and output you are running.

Comment: I took your code exactly, the difference I made is when running client code from another machine I changed the address  to the server's IP address in the local network. and the output is always "::ffff:127.0.0.1" which makes sense because in the server code, you make the fetch at the end and that is the value that keeps coming

Comment: Adding just `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` instead of both working? The fetch in server won't `console.log` because console.log is in `myService`. The function of that fetch in server is to initialize the SOAP server, which is inside GET /. It will execute only once per server lifetime and won't print anything. The printing will be done once per `client.js` execution. If you send any data into body (make request POST) of fetch from client.js, you can see the data is from client.js. Test it in a (ideally remote) developer preview server, not on localhost.